# New data on categorical-only neural net

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am training a classifier based on a neural network using neuralnet package for training and nnet for one-hot encoding of variables.
All variables on the model are categorical. The data consists of 15 labels and 6 independant variables (predictors) that account for 64 dummy variables, so the whole dataframe has 79 columns.
The data comes from 2 year records of monthly updated data.
The model is ready and i need to use it to predict january.2018 outcome.
The problem arises when i try to compute the new data with the model, as once it is coded as dummy variables it does not have the same number of variables as the training data.

for example:
training data: Imagine Size and Speed  are predictors and Animal is the class.
Size can be either (Big, Small)
Speed can be either (Fast, Slow)
Animal can be either (Dog, Turtle)

My data is:

```
 Speed    Size    Animal
 Fast     Big     Dog
 Fast     Small   Dog
 Slow     Big     Turtle
```

Once one-hot coded, using class.ind function from nnet package i get

```
  Fast  Slow  Big  Small  Dog  Turtle
   1     0     1     0     1      0  
   1     0     0     1     1      0   
   0     1     1     0     0      1
```

the problem comes when new data doesnt have any row with one factor level, say new data only contains animals whose speed is "Fast", then once dummy coded i get only 5 variables instead of the 6 from the training data and i cannot compute using the neuralnet, as i get

Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

How can i code the new data so it has all the factor levels anyways?

Answer (score -1):

You could, for example, introduce one row for each class of animal, then, create the dummy variables, and finally remove the "fake" rows.